# Simplifying integer inequalities to equality

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I try (in Mathematica 10)

```
FullSimplify[l >= l1 + l2, {l <= l1 + l2, Element[l | l1 | l2, Integers]}]
```

But that gives back

```
l >= l1 + l2
```

Whereas I expected

```
l == l1 + l2
```

However, (as stated in the comments)

```
FullSimplify[l >= l1 + l2 && l <= l1 + l2]
```

yields

```
l == l1 + l2
```

Superficially these two variants (inequality as assumption, or as equation) look equivalent. **What is the technical difference between the two?**

To counter the claim that my question is easily answered with the documentation or that it is a simple mistake, the documentation for FullSimplify reads

> Assumptions can consist of equations, inequalities, domain
>   specifications such as x[Element]Integers, and logical combinations
>   of these.

which led me to believe my initial attempt should be equivalent to the solution given in the comments.

Comment: `FullSimplify[l >= l1 + l2 && l <= l1 + l2]`

Comment: Not even full...Simplify[l>=l1+l2&&l<=l1+l2]

Comment: Or `Reduce[{l >= l1 + l2, l <= l1 + l2}, l]`...

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks, I refined the question to understand the nuance between my attempt and your solution. I don't think it's a "simple mistake", because according to the documentation Simplify accepts inequalities as assumptions. To me it is then unexpected behavior that these two are different.

Comment: The technical difference is that `l == l1 + l2` is **simpler** than `l >= l1 + l2 && l <= l1 + l2` but not simpler than `l >= l1 + l2` (as measured by ``Simplify`SimplifyCount[expr]``). Note: a `SimplifyCount` function is given in the docs for [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html).  See also [(26172)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26172/how-do-i-invoke-the-default-complexity-function).

Comment: Another reason is that there does not seem to be a transformation in the default `TransformationFunctions` that will transform `l >= l1 + l2.` under the assumption `l <= l1 + l2`.  (AFAIR, I couldn't find one a couple of days ago.  I should have though ciao's first comment would be tried internally.  Maybe it is, but a custom `ComplexityFunction` that prefers `==` to `>=` didn't work.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Reduce[l >= l1 + l2 && l <= l1 + l2 && 
  Element[l | l1 | l2, Integers], l]

(*  (C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && l1 == C[1] && l2 == C[2] && 
 l == C[1] + C[2]   *)
```