# How does `Simplify` resolve `LeafCount` ties?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, documentation, implementation-details

The documentation for `ComplexityFunction` says

> With the default setting ComplexityFunction->Automatic, forms are ranked primarily according to their LeafCount, with corrections to treat integers with more digits as more complex.

and

```
LeafCount[-a - b] == LeafCount[-(a + b)] == 7
>> True
```

so I would expect that `Simplify` would not change either expression. But

```
Simplify[-a - b]
>> -a - b

Simplify[-(a + b)]
>> -a - b
```

seems to imply that Mathematica considers the expression `-a - b` to be strictly simpler than `-(a + b)`. Why is it doing so, since the two expressions seem to have the same complexity as measured by `LeafCount`? I'm not sure whether to interpret the quoted sentence in the documentation as saying that the integer-digit correction to `LeafCount` is the *only* correction, or if it is just giving the integer-digit correction as one example of multiple corrections.

Comment: The automatic `ComplexityFunction` is  `SimplifyCount` in [ComplexityFunction >>  Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)

Comment: tparker  it is in the last section in the linked page. It also gives the same value for both expressions  because both functions are seen as `Plus[Times[-1, a], Times[-1, b]]`.

Comment: @kglr Great, thanks. Convert to an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Similar: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26172/how-do-i-invoke-the-default-complexity-function

Comment: @kglr, tparker: Forgive me, but both `LeafCount` and `SimplifyCount` yield ties.  I don't see how the question (how ties are resolved) has been answered yet.

Comment: Note that `-(a + b)` *evaluates* to `-a - b`, so `Simplify` is irrelevant.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good point. kglr's comment answers both the explicit question "explain this particular behavior" and the implicit question "clarify the `LeafCount` documentation" in the body of the OP, so I accepted their posted answer (although ironically, as written it only answers the implicit question). I've spun the question off in the title as a separate question at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153273/how-does-simplify-resolve-simplifycount-ties.

Comment: tparker please  unaccept my answer  so that i can delete it

Comment: @MichaelE2 or Mr.Wizard, i would expect a downvote on the question before one on an accepted answer.

Comment: @kglr Why? Even if it's a simple mistake, I think your answer is useful.

Comment: tparker, (despite the wrong example)  I think your question is a good one and its title  is exceptionally clear.

Comment: @kglr So why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @kglr I wasn't me. I usually expect someone to state a reason for the DV.  I usually only DV answers that do not do what they claim to do or are in some way "dangerous" and I think should be deleted. That happens rarely, and even more rarely does it have anything at all to do with the quality of the question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you for  your clarification re the downvote on my (now deleted) answer.