# How does Simplify resolve SimplifyCount ties?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, implementation-details

The expressions `a (b + c) + b c` and `a b + (a + b) c` are equivalent and equally complex as measured by `SimplifyCount`:

```
Reduce[a (b + c) + b c == a b + (a + b) c]
(* True *)

SimplifyCount[a (b + c) + b c] == SimplifyCount[a b + (a + b) c] == 9
(* True *)
```

And unlike the example that I used in [How does `Simplify` resolve `LeafCount` ties?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153237/how-does-simplify-resolve-leafcount-ties), the two expressions are not automatically simplified to the same expression before `Simplify` evaluates them:

```
a (b + c) + b c
(* b c + a (b + c) *)

a b + (a + b) c
(* a b + (a + b) c *)

a (b + c) + b c === a b + (a + b) c
(* False *)
```

Nevertheless, `Simplify` converts the latter expression into the former:

```
Simplify[a (b + c) + b c]
(* b c + a (b + c) *)

% === a (b + c) + b c
(* True *)

Simplify[a b + (a + b) c]
(* b c + a (b + c) *)

% === a b + (a + b) c
(* False *)
```

How does `Simplify` decide which expression is simpler, if they have the same `SimplifyCount`?

My guess is that it always breaks ties by going with whichever expression comes last in canonical order:

```
Sort[{a (b + c) + b c, a b + (a + b) c}]
(* {a b + (a + b) c, b c + a (b + c)} *)
```

Is this always the case? If so, then `Simplify` actually uses a total order on expressions, rather than the total preorder given by `SimplifyCount`.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is not just a clarification of your previous question, linked above.

Comment: @MichaelE2 While I didn't realize this when I posted it, the answer to my previous question had nothing at all to do with the behavior of `Simplify` - the "tie" was completely trivial because `Simplify` was evaluating the *same expression* in both instances. Since there was no actual nontrivial `SimplifyCount` tie, the premise of my question was invalid. This question really does concern a nontrivial `SimplifyCount` tie, so its answer will be unrelated to the answer to my previous question.

Comment: I marked the older question as "a simple mistake" -- let this question stand as the corrected/clarified version.  ( @MichaelE2 )

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Originally, given the accepted answer, it seemed a duplicate of [(26172)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26172), which contains the [same answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26177/4999)!, despite the semantic differences in the stated questions; [tparker's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153237?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment409206_153237) makes them seem more like duplicates. But [ilian's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153237?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment409168_153237) shows it is indeed a simple mistake. Let it stand.

Comment: @tparker I don't see anything in the prior question that would not *also* be addressed if this question is adequately answered.  You did not realize that `Simplify` was redundant in that example so it really has nothing to do with `Simplify`, and if it were corrected it would become equivalent to this one I believe.  You might instead ask "why does `-(a + b)` evaluate to `-a - b` but that is yet again a different question and not the one you asked, as I read it.  I don't mean to discourage you; I find *this* an interesting question and you have my vote on it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I've come around to agree with you.